# solaris on sparc not booting automatically on poweron

Tags: boot, solaris

My environment : *SunOS solaris 5.11 11.3 sun4v sparc SUNW, SPARC-Enterprise-T5120*

*eeprom* showed `auto-boot?=false`

So I used command `eeprom auto-boot?=true` and eeprom would show `auto-boot?=true`

I used `shutdown -i0 -g0 -y` to shutdown my system went back to `sc>` and typed `poweron`

but still it's not booting to the OS and I have to manually boot using boot command

Then I look at *eeprom* and it was back to `auto-boot?=false`

http://unixhowto.filodownunder.com/?p=690

i am doing exactly the same as mentioned above

Comment: what is your `boot-device` set to? I'm assuming it's valid and that the system booted since you seem to be showing output from the eeprom seem to hint that it's ok. Normally if the system fails to boot, it's going to be from a bad boot device or a hardware issue. Are you watching the system post at the console? You should be able to see there why it's failing to boot. I'm rusty on my ALOM cmds, but from the OS, you could try `fmadm faulty`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some hardware fault. More information will be available in server Power-On-Self-Test output. You could get in in console.

To fix auto-boot you need to fix hardware fault or to set another OBP variable

```
eeprom auto-boot-on-error?=true
```